# NPAPI SetProperty(NPIdentifier name, const NPVariant *value); value always null

Tags: html, google-chrome, npapi

HTML:

```
var embed1 = document.getElementById('yyqtest');
      embed1.testProperty=5;
```

But, in my plugin: `SetProperty(NPIdentifier name, const NPVariant *value);`
     value always null! Why?

The same code, in firefox is run OK, the *value is 5

My Chrome version is:

> 16.0.912.63 m

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could speculate, but you've provided absolutely no useful details. I can tell you with a fair amount of certainty that the problem is not due to a new incompatibility in your version of Chrome (unless you installed that from source control directly?) so the problem is most likely somewhere in your code; however, since you haven't posted any of your code other than a bit of javascript there is no way to guess.

Barring that, let me give you a few debugging tips:

First, try using an object tag instead of an embed; I've just had weird issues with object tags.

Second, are you absolutely certain that the SetProperty on your NPObject is even being called? Is the plugin being loaded? How do you know the value is always null? Did you test it afterwords, and is it possible it just hasn't been changed because the function was never called?

What OS are you on? Have you tried attaching a debugger? Have you considered using FireBreath instead of doing it from scratch so that you don't have to worry about knowing all of these details?

If none of that helps I highly recommend you add a *lot* of detail to your question and try again, because what you have given doesn't give any of the details we'd need to do more than speculate wildly.